# Ruby on Rails layouts...except and only bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I have a controller with the following layout logic

```
layout 'sessions', :except => :privacy
  layout 'static', :only => :privacy
```

The issue is that Rails seems to ignore the first line of code and the layout "sessions" is not applied for any actions.  It simply thinks to render the static layout for privacy and no layout for the rest.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another option is to define a method for your layout call, like so:

```
layout :compute_layout
```

and then

```
def compute_layout
  action_name == "privacy" ? "static" : "sessions" 
end
```

However this is really only useful when you want to determine the layout at runtime based on some runtime parameter (like a variable being set). In your example, that does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: this is what i resorted to... +1 for the "action_name"...didn't know about that

Comment: action_name is also easy to throw into a case/when/then block when you have to deal with more than 2 actions.

Answer (score 26):

The reason this doesn't work is because you can only have global one layout declaration per controller.  The `:only` and `:except` conditions just differentiate between actions that should get the specified layout and the ones that are excluded get rendered without a layout.  In other words, a layout declaration always affects all actions that use default rendering.

To override you simply specify a layout when you render like one of the following examples inside an action:

```
render :layout => 'static'
render :action => 'privacy', :layout => 'static'
render :layout => false # Don't render a layout
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the one accepted for the case described.

Answer (score 3):

You can just specify `layout :static` where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also dynamically determine the layout within your controller:

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController

    layout Proc.new { |controller| (controller.action_name == 'privacy') ? 'static' : 'sessions' }

    ...
end
```

If more actions within the controller are sharing the same layout:

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController

    layout Proc.new { |controller| ['action1', 'action2'].include?(controller.action_name) ? 'layout1' : 'layout2' }

    ...
end
```

Source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render